# Protege sees relationship, Virtuoso doesn't

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, protege, virtuoso

Viewing the [go-plus ontology](http://geneontology.org/page/download-ontology) in a freshly installed, stock Protégé 5, I found a useful inference in the entities tab for http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0003215:

***'cardiac right ventricle morphogenesis' 'results in morphogenesis of' some 'cardiac ventricle'***

*'results in morphogenesis of'* in this case is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/RO_0002298 and *'cardiac ventricle'* is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0002082

If I load the same ontology into Virtuoso Open Source 07.20.3217 and describe http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0003215, no relationship with 'cardiac ventricle' is listed.  [(Even after enabling OWL inference.)](http://kidehen.blogspot.com/2014/01/demonstrating-reasoning-via-sparql.html?view=flipcard#!/2014/01/demonstrating-reasoning-via-sparql.html)

However, http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GO_0003215 **is** linked to an anonymous node with

```
rdf:type           owl:Restriction 
owl:onProperty     n3:RO_0002298 
owl:someValuesFrom n3:UBERON_0002080
```

Where `n3` is `http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/`

Is there a Virtuoso configuration that would make this relationship clear in a `describe` view?

Is there some concise SPARQL syntax that would make the relationship clear?  Currently, I'm using

```
select distinct ?goid (str(?goterm) as ?go_str)
?svf (str(?anatomy ) as ?anat_str)
where
{
  ?goid obo:hasOBONamespace 'biological_process'^^xsd:string .
  ?goid  rdfs:label ?goterm .
  ?goid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?parent .
  ?parent owl:someValuesFrom* ?svf .
  ?svf rdfs:subClassOf+
  <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/UBERON_0001062> .
  ?svf rdfs:label ?anatomy
}
```

Comment: Virtuoso-specific questions are often answered more quickly and accurately via Virtuoso-specific resources, such as the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things in play here.

You can use Property Paths for transitivity, as described in comment by @ASKW.

If you want to leverage Virtuoso's [built-in reasoning](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html#rdfsparqlrulemake) for relationship types described by [RDF Schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/) (`rdfs:subClassOf`, `rdfs:subPropertyOf`, `rdfs:subClassOf`) or [OWL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-overview/) (`owl:equivalentProperty`, `owl:equivalentClass`, `owl:SymmetricProperty`, `owl:inverseOf`, etc.), then you can leverage the inference rules pragma as described in @MarkMiller's comments (note reference to a [blog post about that usage pattern](http://kidehen.blogspot.com/2014/01/demonstrating-reasoning-via-sparql.html)).

If you want to write custom inference rules (i.e., [use SPARQL as your Inference Rules language](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/reasoning-inference-using-british-royal-family-part-idehen)), then you will need Virtuoso 8.0 (coming soon) which delivers that capability. Note, this is the ultimate solution, as you can write your own algorithms using SPARQL.

Comment: When will Virtuoso 8 be released? It's the first time I read about it.

Answer (score 2):

How do you enable OWL reasoning in Virtuoso? You should know that it doesn't support OWL DL reasoning, but only some kind of rule-based reasoning which only covers a small part of OWL DL. Protege on the other hand supports OWL DL reasoning by means of reasoners like HermiT, Pellet, etc.

If you mean by "enable OWL inference" just using SPARQL 1.1 proeprty paths on the `rdfs:subClassOf` relation, then this is far away from OWL DL reasoning. It just means to consider the transitive closure of that relation from a start node in the graph, nothing more and no more magic behind.

Comment: Virtuoso has a "DEFINE  input:inference" pragma that can precede a SPARQL query.  After following the tutorial ( http://kidehen.blogspot.com/2014/01/demonstrating-reasoning-via-sparql.html ), the relationship "Harry sibling-of William" is expanded to "Harry knows William", so I thought that it was doing something beyond  SAPRQL 1.1 property paths.  But I know very little about this kind of logic.  I did try applying some input:inference pragmas to my heart ventricle problem.

Comment: Ok, but this needs a complex set of rules to get the inferred facts of your example. Note, for full OWL DL, there is - as far as I know - no rule-based approach.